getting the jacoco.exec file as 0kb , nothing capture in the exec file . Nothing capture in jacoco.exec
I started my application with jacocoagent like this
start.sh file :(start.sh & jacocoagent & application.jar present in same location)
export JAVA_OPTS="-javaagent:jacocoagent.jar=destfile=jacoco.exec"
nohup java ${JAVA_OPTS} -jar application.jar >> application.log &
After I started the application using sh start.sh the application started . and run the testcases in the same server . but the jacoco.exec file created but nothing written in that exec.
please help me in this if any other thing need to do let me know .
Thanking You in Advance

Download jacocoagent.jar
put jacocoagent.jar , application.jar & start script in same location.
write the start script like :
JAVA_OPTS="-javaagent:jacocoagent.jar=destfile=jacoco.exec"
nohup java ${JAVA_OPTS} -jar application.jar
start the application using sh start.sh and it's started also .
execute the testcases in that same server where the application running .

